# Handling SSAS Database ( Cube OLAP)

Tags: ssis, ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube

Can we make a Failover Cluster with SSAS database cube ?

The idea is that if a server is no available, user can connect to the second server automatically with Excel.

We can do this with SSIS : Data Source=172.1.1.1;Failover Partner=172.1.1.2;

Can we do the same thing with SSAS ?

Thanks for your help.

N.

Comment: Describe your setup more. Do you have two servers in a Windows failover cluster? Is node1 running SSAS but when you reboot nodeA then SSAS fails over to nodeB? Does your cluster have a virtual name you can connect to which automatically routes to the right node? Or do you have SSAS running on both servers and a copy of the cubes on both nodes and you want to load balance queries?